# Ajax rendering octobercms backend partial

Tags: php, ajax, partial, octobercms

i'm building my first plugin in octobercms and i want to use the AJAX Framework like this way.

`$/prestasafe/erp/models/invoice/_payment_tab.htm`

In the backend, i render some partials, and i want to update them with ajax.

There is my code in my partial view:

```
 <input 
                    type="button" 
                    data-request="onAddPaiment"

                    data-request-update="paiment_tab: '#paiment-tab'" 
                    class="btn btn-primary" name="add_paiement" id="add_paiement" value="Ajouter">
```

There is my code in my backend controller:

```
 public function onAddPaiment()
    {
        $montant    = Input::get('montant');
        $montant    = str_replace(',','.',$montant);
        $type       = Input::get('paiement_type');
        $date       = Input::get('date_addpaiement');
        $id_invoice = (int)Input::get('id_invoice');
        $data       = array('id_invoice' => $id_invoice, 'type' => $type, 'montant' => $montant, 'date' => $date);
        DB::table('prestasafe_erp_invoice_paiements')->insert($data);

        $this->vars['invoice'] = InvoiceModel::findOrFail($id_invoice);
        return [
            'paiment_tab' => $this->makePartial('$/prestasafe/erp/models/invoice/_payment_tab.htm')
        ];

    }
```

This code works well.

But, on the update template i have this error:

```
"The partial '_paiment_tab.htm' is not found." on line 91 of /Users/guillaume/Sites/october/modules/system/Traits/ViewMaker.php
```

what's is wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: can you once check this your error shows `"The partial '_paiment_tab.htm'` and you created file named `_payment_tab.htm` so is it problem ? or it is typo mistake can you please confirm

Comment: YEs thanks to you but if i change that it's doesnt works too. The path is not good, it don't takes the partial of my plugin. I've found an other solution but i prefere to do in the best way.